# How to extract a particular number from a long string of data using Oracle SQL?

Tags: oracle

I need the numbers extracted from the string of data contained in a column of a table.

Example string :

```
<strong>Customer Name</strong>: Hit -  julaifnaf afbafbaf Caraballo Pichardo vs PICHARDO ALBERTO<br />  
<strong>Address</strong>: NA -  abdcinfainaf 42982542542 vs xx<br />
<strong>Country of citizenship</strong>: NA<br />
<strong>Country of residency</strong>: NA<br />
<strong>Date of birth</strong>: NA - xx vs Nov-72<br />
<strong>Place of birth</strong>: NA<br />
<strong>Identification Number</strong>: **1**<br />
<strong>emailDetails</strong>: <br/>
<b>Subject: </b>abcdejnfanfa <br/>
<b>Sent To: </b>abced@test.com<br/>
```

In the above example string the number I need extracted `1`.
The length of the stings and position of the record vary,
but the numbers to be extracted always come after `Identification Number</strong>:` and before `<br /><strong>`.

What function can I use to extract this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(
           column_name,
           '<strong>Identification Number</strong>:.*?(\d+).*?<br />',
           1,
           1,
           NULL,
           1
         )
       ) AS id_number
FROM   table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select 
    regexp_replace(column_name,'.*<strong>Identification Number</strong>:[^>\d]*(\d+)[^>\d]*<br\s*/>.*', '\1', 1, 0, 'inm') as id 
from html;
```

PS it's not very reliable solution though, because you can't parse **any** HTML using RegExp's.

Output:

```
         ID
-----------
          1
```